# jquery, why .data() is not working in internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

is there any way to make data() working in internet explorer, for example if you try this example in Chrome or Firefox it will work, but it does not in ie :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>A div</div>
    <button>Get "blah" from the div</button>
    <button>Set "blah" to "hello"</button>
    <button>Set "blah" to 86</button>
    <button>Remove "blah" from the div</button>
    <p>The "blah" value of this div is <span>?</span></p>

<script>
$( "button" ).click(function() {
var value;

 switch ( $( "button" ).index( this ) ) {
  case 0 :
  value = $( "div" ).data( "blah" );
  break;
case 1 :
  $( "div" ).data( "blah", "hello" );
  value = "Stored!";
  break;
case 2 :
  $( "div" ).data( "blah", 86 );
  value = "Stored!";
  break;
case 3 :
  $( "div" ).removeData( "blah" );
  value = "Removed!";
  break;
}

  $( "span" ).text( "" + value );
});
 </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

This is the last example from : http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Perhaps including the specific version of IE would be helpful.

Comment: Nothing wrong - go to the docs, then to "additional notes": `Note that this method currently does not provide cross-platform support for setting data on XML documents, as Internet Explorer does not allow data to be attached via expando properties.
`

Comment: IE11 is reporting no problems works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML and JS code is ok. Only I would like to wrap JS code into

```
$(function(){
  // js code
});
```

I added a couple of alert(), which return results are as expected

**[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/zuu1wecc/)** for fiddle

Here is completely HTML/JS code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Jquery data - jsFiddle demo by User86745458</title>  
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){
    $( "button" ).click(function() {
        var value;
         switch ( $( "button" ).index( this ) ) {
          case 0 :
          value = $( "div" ).data( "blah" );
          alert($( "div" ).data( "blah" ));
          break;
        case 1 :
          $( "div" ).data( "blah", "hello" );
          value = "Stored!";
          alert($( "div" ).data( "blah" ));
          break;
        case 2 :
          $( "div" ).data( "blah", 86 );
          value = "Stored!";
          alert($( "div" ).data( "blah" ));
          break;
        case 3 :
          $( "div" ).removeData( "blah" );
          value = "Removed!";
          alert($( "div" ).data( "blah" ));
          break;
        }
        $( "span" ).text( "" + value );
    });
});
//]]> 
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>A div</div>
    <button>Get "blah" from the div</button>
    <button>Set "blah" to "hello"</button>
    <button>Set "blah" to 86</button>
    <button>Remove "blah" from the div</button>
    <p>The "blah" value of this div is <span>?</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jsfiddle does not have any problem, all my code  works fine in jsfiddle, maybe jsfiddle have a special setup. but try to load a page from your machine to ie.

Comment: I put the code from fiddle and the page is ok when running in IE11, Please make sure add 'http:' at front of jquery.js url as src='http: //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js

Comment: I pulled all html/javascript code into my answer. Could you please copy it and run it again? Thanks.